# Is the identity in unital, simple, purely infinite $C^*$-algebra always infinite?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, c-star-algebras

I'd like to prove that the identity, $I$, of a unital, simple, purely infinite $C^*$-algebra is always an infinite projection. What I'm hoping is that the following is true:

If $p$ in $\mathfrak{A}$ is an infinite projection and $p\leq q$, then $q$ is also infinite.

The original result would of course follow from this, as every projection is bounded above by $I$. Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $p$ is infinite, there exists $r\leq p$ with $r\ne p$ and $r$ equivalent to $p$. That is, there exists $v$ with $v^*v=r$, $vv^*=p$.

Note that $v=pvr$, so in particular $(q-p)v=0$, and $v(q-p)=0$.

Now let $s=r+q-p$. Then $s$ is a proper subprojection of $q$. Let $w=v+q-p$. Then
$$
w^*w=(v^*+q-p)(v+q-p)=v^*v+q-p=r+q-p=s,
$$
$$
ww^*=vv^*+q-p=p+q-p=q.
$$
So $q$ is infinite.

Comment: Thanks very much! Very slick.

Comment: And this does not need that $A$ is purely infinite, right ?

Comment: No. It proves the second paragraph in the question.